# Does INNODB storage engine provide default partition pruning in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-design

I know we can define Partition Pruning explicitly. But, I want to know if it is provided by default. I have tried the official documentation site for MySQL. The site says, "In MySQL 5.6.8 and later, partition pruning is disabled for all tables using a storage engine that provides automatic partitioning, such as the NDB storage engine used by MySQL Cluster". A quick and to the point answer with explanation will be worth.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:  Watch out for some subtle terminology...

InnoDB does not have "automatic partitioning"; one must explicitly specify partitioning.  NDB automatically partitions the data.

InnoDB will automatically prune down to the partition(s) that the `WHERE` clause specifies implicitly via a condition on the 'partition key'.

But, be aware that pruning is often no better than crafting a good composite index on a non-partitioned table.

I claim there are *only* [4 use cases](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) where `PARTITIONing` provides any performance benefit.  Furthermore, I claim that `BY RANGE` is the only flavor that helps.

If you would like to show us your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT`, we can discuss whether `PARTITIONing` is of any benefit.  And, if no benefit, why.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am doing some research and for that reason I wanted to know. Till now I have just started implementing it. If I find something which will help me, I'll ask. Thanks again.